# vscode - disable all file watching for remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm trying to use VS:Code's remote workspace feature on a server that I don't have root access to. I'm limited to 8192 watchers, and VS:code uses all of them because there are lots of files in my build directories. I don't really need file watching that badly, so I was wondering if anyone knows a simple way to just disable it. I've tried adding:

```
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/**": true,
        "**/*/**": true,
```

to my user and remote settings, but it's still attempting to watch everything. Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `"**/*"`? And why not just specifically exlude your build directories?